# Appropriate boundary conditions for heat equation with source

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics, boundary-conditions, software, differential-equations

I'm attempting to solve the heat equation with a time varying source term $Q$. The boundary conditions are that the temperature over the 2-D area is equal to $T_{min}$ at $t=0$ and the Neumann boundary condition is equal to $0$ to signify an insulating perimeter.

The equation that I'm using is

$\rho c \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}  =k(\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}) + Q(t)$

The principle issue is that regardless of the value of the source term it seems to have no effect on the result. The result stays at $T_{min}$ over the entire area.

**Update:**

This is my code (for specifics about the equations):

```
rc = (8950) (385); (*density, Kg/m3 x heat capacity, J/Kg K*)
k = 385; (*thermal conductivity, W/m K*)

minT = 300;(*T, K*)
maxT = 500;(*T, K*)
time = 20;(*seconds*)

omega[t_] :=0;
q[t_] := Sin[t Pi/time];

maxX = 10/100; (*m*)
maxY = 5/100; (*m*)

fea[cell_] := {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Area" -> (maxX maxY)/
          cell^2}}}}

solt = NDSolve[{
    rc D[u[x, y, t], t] - 
      k (D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]) + q[t] == 
     NeumannValue[omega[t], True],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == minT, t == 0]},
   u, {x, 0, maxX}, {y, 0, maxY}, {t, 0, time},
   Method -> fea[50]]
```

**Update 2:**

In light of Gert's comments:

- The boundaries are $T(x,y,0)=T_{min}$ and $\Big(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\Big)_{x boundary}=0$ and $\Big(\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\Big)_{y boundary}=0$
- The shape of it is a rectangle, as shown below:

[image: rectangle]

- The perimeter is perfectly insulated, so there's no conduction over the entire perimeter
- $Q(t) = \sin(t Pi/t_{max}$)...it's meant to start at zero at the beginning of the time domain, peak in the middle, and return to zero at the end of the time domain.

**Bonus:**

What should be the units of $Q$?

Comment: Could you specify $Q(t)$ and the Neumann boundary condition specifically used? Do you mean that there's no conduction over the entire perimeter?

Comment: @Gert, does the update help?

Comment: To some it will but I'm not familiar with matlab notation. Shame, because I love this kind of problems. So far I understand this: $T(x,y,0)=T_{min}$. Also, maybe: $\Big(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\Big)_{x boundary}=0$ and $\Big(\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\Big)_{y boundary}=0$. 'AmIright?'

Comment: @Gert, those are the boundaries, yes. And, it's actually Mathematica...=)

Comment: Does it have a shape? ;-)

Comment: As for your conduction question the perimeter is perfectly insulated, so yes.

Comment: It's a rectangle.

Comment: And $Q(t)=\sin(\pi t)$?

Comment: No, it's $Q(t) = \sin(t  Pi/T_{max}$)...its meant to start at zero at the beginning of the time domain, peak in the middle, and return to zero at the end of the time domain.

Comment: OK, got it. Will get to work now. Ta.

Comment: @Gert, I mistyped it the first time...it's updated now.

Comment: Got it. Ta. See you soon.

Comment: The integral of your heat input over all time is (numerically) tiny - $40/\pi\approx12.7$. Also, the equation seems to imply that the heat is equally distributed over the entire area - is that correct?  And the heat capacity, according to your equation, is numerically 8950*385=$3.4\cdot 10^6$. This predicts a temperature rise of  $3.7\cdot10^{-6} K$. Perhaps you are doing everything right, except units...

Comment: @Floris, I've updated the $Q$ term to $\frac{-144000}{(maxX  maxY  maxZ)} * Sin(\frac{\pi}{\tau} t)$ which gave a 170 Kelvin rise in temperature in 4 seconds.

Comment: @Floris The heat is evenly distributed over the area.

Comment: If your problem is 2D and the heat is evenly distributed with insulating boundaries, can't you solve it as a 0D problem? You have a heat capacity and an input, and get back the integral of the heat input with a scaling term.

Comment: @Floris, I'm going to ultimately move to not having an even distribution, so I'd like to solve it as a 2-d problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second of course 'user115350's comment about $Q$, it should really be something like $Q(t)=Q_0\sin\Big(\frac{2\pi}{\tau}t\Big)$, where $\tau$ is the *period* of the heating cycle.

I would also recommend a small transformation like $T \to u$, where:
$u=T-T_{min}$ because it makes the initial condition homogeneous:

$$u(x,y,0)=0$$
Let's have a look at the problem in one dimension first:

The PDE can then be rewritten as:
$$u_t=\kappa u_{xx}+\frac{Q(t)}{\rho c}$$
Or:
$$u_t-\kappa u_{xx}=\frac{Q(t)}{\rho c}$$
Solve the homogeneous PDE first:
$$u_t-\kappa u_{xx}=0$$
Ansatz: 
$$u(x,t)=X(x)\Gamma(t)$$
Separation:
$$\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}=\kappa\frac{X''}{X}=-m^2$$
$$X=A\sin\Big(\frac{m}{\sqrt{\kappa}}x\Big)+B\cos\Big(\frac{m}{\sqrt{\kappa}}x\Big)$$
$$X'(0)=0 \implies B=0$$
$$X'(L)=A\sin\Big(\frac{m}{\sqrt{\kappa}}L\Big)=0$$
$$\frac{m}{\sqrt{\kappa}}L=n\pi$$
$$m^2=\frac{n^2 \pi^2 \kappa}{L^2}$$
For:
$$n=1,2,3,4,...$$
$$X(x)=\sin\Big(\frac{n\pi\sqrt{\kappa}}{L}\Big)$$
$$u(x,t)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \Gamma_n(t)\sin\Big(\frac{n\pi\sqrt{\kappa}}{L}x\Big)$$
Now we go back to:
$$u_t-\kappa u_{xx}=\frac{Q(t)}{\rho c}$$

Inserting $u(x,t)$ and expanding $\frac{Q(t)}{\rho c}$ into a Fourier series then allows to obtain (a complicated) analytical solution (with some further doodling).

But trying this approach for **the two dimensional case** quickly became nightmarish because its an eigenvalue problem for both $X(x)$ and $Y(x)$.

Comment: I'm still looking at it, but I want $Q$ to stay in the same domain over the period, so wouldn't it be $\frac{\pi}{\tau}$ instead of $2\pi$?

Comment: So, are you saying instead of $\rho c \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}  =k(\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}) + Q(t)$ it should be $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}  - k(\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}) =\frac{Q(t)}{\rho c}$? And, in yours, is $k$ the thermal conductivity?

Comment: $\kappa=k / (\rho c)$ is the heat diffusivity ('kappa'). REe. the $\tau$, choose value as needed.

Comment: Finally, your model does not account for *any* convective heat  losses. Is that realistic?

Comment: Yeah, I understand; this was kind of a worst-case situation. Where could I find some guidance on modifying the Neumann condition to account for radiative losses?

Comment: In your temperature range, *convective losses* should be sufficient as a loss function. An element $dxdy$ would be losing $dQ(x,y,t)=-2h(T(x,y,t)-T_{environment})dxdy$ for 2 sided losses (Newton's cooling law). It would be cautious to derive the whole PDE from scratch though.

Comment: And the boundary conditions aren't affected by whatever form of heat loss either.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1. unit of Q will be $\frac{W}{m^3}$
2. $Q=sin(...)$ only gives you maximum heat source of 1 $\frac{W}{m^3}$. It seems too small to make significant change. Could you try $Q=1000*sin(...)$
3. My understanding Dirichlet is boundary condition but not for initial condition. I'm not sure if it is the case in your code library. You can check.

Comment: The units answer is very helpful...of course, since my area is only 2-d I can just do $\frac{W}{m^2}$. Should it be negative?

Comment: Even in 2d, there is thickness assumed. So the unit will still be $W/m^3$. In your model, you should declare the thickness assumption. The heat source can be negative, meaning it takes heat out as coolant.

Comment: The temperature only seems to increase when the value is negative.

Comment: as a diagnosis, you can use constant value for q, run simulation and see the response.

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to define q(x, y, t).

Comment: I made $Q$ constant and the temperature value only goes positive when $Q$ is negative. It goes positive faster now that it's a constant. I've also tried defining it to be valid over the 2-d area and again, $Q$ must be negative.

Comment: This makes sense (i.e. negative Q) because in the code you move the  Q to the LHS.

Comment: @user115350: "* I'm wondering if you need to define q(x, y, t)*" No, $Q(t)$  simply means it's space invariant: a uniform heat flux over the whole domain, variable in time only.

Comment: *This makes sense (i.e. negative Q) because in the code you move the Q to the LHS*. True.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

First - you have a sign error in your code:

```
solt = NDSolve[{
    rc D[u[x, y, t], t] - 
      k (D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]) + q[t] == <<<<<<<<<<
     NeumannValue[omega[t], True],
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == minT, t == 0]},
   u, {x, 0, maxX}, {y, 0, maxY}, {t, 0, time},
   Method -> fea[50]]
```

it should either be

```
      k (D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]) - q[t] ==
```

or

```
      (k (D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + D[u[x, y, t], y, y]) + q[t]) ==
```

That's why you need a negative sign on your Q in order to get a positive change in the temperature

Second - you are doing a 2D problem but using 3D units. The heat capacity of the sheet is going to be $c\rho t$ - without the thickness you are computing the heat capacity of a thick slab of material. That's OK if you really are modeling a 3D situation with symmetry, so that the heat generated is really "heat per unit length, per unit area".

Third - as I mentioned in a comment, your initial conditions didn't really allow for a very large shift in temperature - large heat capacity, small amount of heat input. The integral of your original heat input function was orders of magnitude smaller than the heat needed to get even a small change in temperature - the solver may have terminated without any shift at all due to numerical approximation issues.

Finally - you should be able to calculate the temperature change for this situation with pencil and paper. Doing so will help you figure out how to treat the units of heat input. I would recommend picking a "thin" slab (say 1 mm thick), and computing the thermal rise for a given heat per unit area.

Comment: this is for a 2-d cross section of a solenoid coil.